# Expand and hide div on click href

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want `<div>` to expand and hide a `<div>` on the click of an `<a>` tag. I am using bootstrap and I want to hide the `<div> col-md-4` but the button is inside `col-md-8`.

By clicking `<a>` tag `col-md-4` should hide to left portion and the width of `col-md-8` should increase. How would I do this?

My code

```css
.advanced_filter {width:100%; height:500px; background:red;}
.advanced_filter span {color:#fff; position:relative; top:50%; width:100%;}
.search_list {width:100%; height:500px; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="advanced_filter">
            <span>Advanced Filter Menu</span>
          </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <a href="#">Hide / Show Advanced Filter</a>
         <div class="search_list">
            
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootsrap [**Collapse**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/).

Use `data-toggle` and `data-target` in your `<a>` element with a `collapse` class in your `advanced_filter` element.

**Demo:**

```css
.advanced_filter {width:100%; height:500px; background:red;}
.advanced_filter span {color:#fff; position:relative; top:50%; width:100%;}
.search_list {width:100%; height:500px; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <div id="hideIt" class="col-md-4 collapse">
         <div class="advanced_filter">
            <span>Advanced Filter Menu</span>
          </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hideIt">Hide / Show Advanced Filter</a>
         <div class="search_list">
            
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

To toggle `col-md-12` class with the parent div of the `<a>` element you will need to use **jQuery** [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like this:

```
$(".col-md-8 a").click(function(){ 
    $("#hideIt").toggle();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('col-md-12');
});
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working [demo **Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/hcuds67x/) showing how to use this jQuery code.

Comment: This code works. But how can i change the col-md-8 to col-md-12 after hiding the div? The div should be full width. Can this be done?

Comment: @User113 You will need to use `jQuery` or `JavaScript` to do it, I don't think it's possible without JS.

Comment: You are welcome, in that case you will just need to use jQuery [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like this: `$(".col-md-8 a").click(function(){ $(this).parent().toggleClass('col-md-12');});`.

Comment: Toggle class is not working. I want to change col-md-8 to col-md-12 for fullwidth otherwise so much space in right side. Can u pls help me?

Comment: @User113 Please check my updated answer, I attached a Demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/hcuds67x/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS

HTML

```
<a href="#someId">my div</a>
<div id="someId">some contents</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: none;
}
:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry @Martin Chaov. I didn't understand the css style? Which div name is this 'div'.

Comment: just copy/paste it in your code. :target will apply the styles based on the hash that's in the URL. The "div" is the tag name for all divs... you will substitute this with your own class name or whatever you want to use. You only need to take care of the fact that selectors have specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery.

Please find the solution here : https://plnkr.co/edit/euf83rEokXvBdWbRvmOw?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="advanced_filt" id="adv">
            <div class="advanced_filter">
            <span>Advanced Filter Menu</span>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-section" id="main">
            <a href="#" id="showHide">Hide / Show Advanced Filter</a>
            <div class="search_list">

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

/* Styles go here */

```
.advanced_filt{
  width : 25%;
  display : inline-block;
  float : left;
}
.main-section{
  width : 75%;
  display : inline-block;
  float : left;
}
.advanced_filter {width:100%; height:500px; background:red;}
.advanced_filter span {color:#fff; position:relative; top:50%; width:100%;}
.search_list {width:100%; height:500px; background:yellow;}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#showHide").click(function(){
          $("#adv").css("display" , "none");
           $("#main").css("width" , "100%");
    }); 
});
```